# XSLT xsl:sequence. What is it good for..?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I know the following question is a little bit of beginners but I need your help to understand a basic concept.

I would like to say first that I'm a XSLT programmer for 3 years and yet there are some new and quite basics things I've been learning here I never knew (In my job anyone learns how to program alone, there is no course involved).

My question is:
What is the usage of `xsl:sequence`?

I have been using `xsl:copy-of` in order to copy node as is, `xsl:apply-templates` in order to modifiy nodes I selected and `value-of` for simple text.

I never had the necessity using `xsl:sequence`. I would appreciate if someone can show me an example of `xsl:sequence` usage which is preferred or cannot be achieved without the ones I noted above.

One more thing, I have read about the `xsl:sequence` definition of course, but I couldn't infer how it is useful.

Answer (score 50):

`<xsl:sequence>` on an atomic value (or sequence of atomic values) is the same as `<xsl:copy-of>` both just return a copy of their input. The difference comes when you consider nodes.

If $n is a single element node, eg as defined by something like

```
<xsl:variable name="n" select="/html"/>
```

Then

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$n"/>
```

Returns a *copy* of the node, it has the same name and child structure but it is a *new* node with a new identity (and no parent).

```
<xsl:sequence select="$n"/>
```

Returns the node $n, The node returned has the same parent as $n and is equal to it by the `is` Xpath operator.

The difference is almost entirely masked in traditional (XSLT 1 style) template usage as you never get access to the result of either operation the result of the constructor is *implicitly* copied to the output tree so the fact that `xsl:sequence` doesn't make a copy is masked.

```
<xsl:template match="a">
   <x>
   <xsl:sequence select="$n"/>
   </x>
</xsl:template>
```

is the same as

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <x>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$n"/>
    </x>
</xsl:template>
```

Both make a new element node and *copy* the result of the content as children of the new node `x`.

However the difference is quickly seen if you use functions.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f="data:,f">

    <xsl:variable name="s">
        <x>hello</x>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        ::
        :: <xsl:value-of select="$s/x is f:s($s/x)"/>
        :: <xsl:value-of select="$s/x is f:c($s/x)"/>
        ::
        :: <xsl:value-of select="count(f:s($s/x)/..)"/>
        :: <xsl:value-of select="count(f:c($s/x)/..)"/>
        ::
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="f:s">
        <xsl:param name="x"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$x"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="f:c">
        <xsl:param name="x"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$x"/>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces

```
$ saxon9 -it main seq.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
::
:: true
:: false
::
:: 1
:: 0
::
```

Here the results of `xsl:sequence` and `xsl:copy-of` are radically different.

Answer (score 32):

The most common use case for xsl:sequence is to return a result from xsl:function.

```
<xsl:function name="f:get-customers">
  <xsl:sequence select="$input-doc//customer"/>
</xsl:function>
```

But it can also be handy in other contexts, for example

```
<xsl:variable name="x" as="element()*">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$something">
       <xsl:sequence select="//customer"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:sequence select="//supplier"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The key thing here is that it returns references to the original nodes, it doesn't make new copies.

Comment: in the second example, does that mean xsl:sequence is better for performance? Where, then, is the advantage of copy-of over xsl:sequence?

Comment: I suspect there are very few cases where you really need xsl:copy-of. Unless you use validation=strict or copy-namespaces=no, perhaps. In most case using xsl:copy-of instead of xsl:sequence will be harmless but there are certainly some cases where it could cause unnecessary and expensive copying unless the optimizer is smart enough to prevent it. But in the example above, the two are not equivalent: $x/.. returns nothing if you make copies, but returns the parents of the original nodes if you select them with xsl:sequence.

Answer (score 9):

Well to return a value of a certain type you use `xsl:sequence` as `xsl:value-of` despite its name always creates a text node (since XSLT 1.0).
So in a function body you use

```
  <xsl:sequence select="42"/>
```

to return an `xs:integer` value, you would use

```
<xsl:sequence select="'foo'"/>
```

to return an `xs:string` value and

```
<xsl:sequence select="xs:date('2013-01-16')"/>
```

to return an `xs:date` value and so on. Of course you can also return sequences with e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="1, 2, 3"/>`.

You wouldn't want to create a text node or even an element node in these cases in my view as it is inefficient.

So that is my take, with the new schema based type system of XSLT and XPath 2.0 a way is needed to return or pass around values of these types and a new construct was needed.

[edit]Michael Kay says in his "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 programmer's reference" about `xsl:sequence`: "This innocent looking instruction introduced in XSLT 2.0 has far reaching effects on the capability of the XSLT language, because it means that XSLT instructions and sequence constructors (and hence functions and templates) become capable of returning any value allowed by the XPath data model. Without it, XSLT instructions could only be used to create new nodes in a result tree, but with it, they can also return atomic values and references to existing nodes.".

Answer (score 0):

Another use is to create a tag only if it has a child. An example is required :

```
<a>
    <b>node b</b>
    <c>node c</c>
</a>
```

Somewhere in your XSLT :

```
<xsl:variable name="foo">
    <xsl:if select="b"><d>Got a "b" node</d></xsl:if>
    <xsl:if select="c"><d>Got a "c" node</d></xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:if test="$foo/node()">
    <wrapper><xsl:sequence select="$foo"/></wrapper>
</xsl:if>
```

You may see the demo here : http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFz

It is way better than testing each tag like this :

```
<xsl:if test="a|b">...</xsl:if>
```

Because you would end up editing it in two places. Also the processing speed would depend on which tags are in your imput. If it is the last one from your test, the engine will test the presence of everyone before. As $foo/node() is an idioms for "is there a child element ?", the engine can optimize it. Doing so, you ease the life of everyone.