# Surprising XSLT/XPath expression type behavior

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I ran into a behavior related to types in XSLT/XPath that I can't explain. Here's a snippet of XSLT that shows the problem (it's not a very useful XSLT, of course, but it represents a pretty minimal demonstration my question):

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:variable name="root">
                <xsl:sequence select="root(.)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="root(.) is  $root">
                Match
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will see that "Match" is *not* displayed. However, if you add `as="node()"` to the `<xsl:variable name="root">` then "Match" *is* displayed.

Can anyone explain help me understand why?

You can plug this XSLT into http://xslttest.appspot.com to explore the problem. Any input XML will work (e.g., `<?xml version="1.0"?><foo/>`).

Thanks,
Josh.

Comment: I believe you will find the answer here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#temporary-trees -- P.S. Your stylesheet  is tagged as `version="1.0"` but it will only work in XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know the difference between a sequence and a variable you may go through the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361629/xslt-xslsequence-what-is-it-good-for).

To summarize, `xsl:variable` without an `as` attribute creates a new document(having its own root node).
Using `as` attribute helps creating an atomic value or a sequence. Here, the variable wouldn't be a root node but will refer to the sequence(s) it contains.

When you use:

```
<xsl:variable name="root">
            <xsl:sequence select="root(.)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

With the condition `<xsl:if test="root(.) is  $root">`, you are testing whether the root of the input XML document is same as the root of the variable `root`, which is `false`.

And when you use:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" as="node()">
```

The condition, `root(.) is  $root` evaluates to `true` as both the input document root and the sequence generated by variable `root` are same.

And of course, as mentioned by `michael.hor257k` this stylesheet shall be versioned `2.0`.

**EDIT:**
Declaring variable in the following way would also make the condition `true()`

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="root(.)"/>
```

Comment: @joshp123 can you close this by accepting the answer by ticking it right if it helps or solves your problem.